# How can I speed up laptop internal webcam capture in Ubuntu 18.04 vs Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, video, webcam, opencv

I am writing C++/opencv code for some image processing routines, and am using my Dell Precision 7730's own webcamera to get test video input.  Video card is Quadro P5200.

I started in Windows 10 using VSE 2015 and opencv 4.1.0.  There I can capture 1280x720 webcam video and display it at 30fps, or whatever rate the camera is putting out.

But I recently switched over to Ubuntu 18.04 with Eclipse (installed on the second SSD) because with our actual external prototype camera, which sends video over UDP packets into Ethernet port, Windows was dropping too many receive packets.  (That's another issue to tackle later, but Ubuntu does not cause any dropped packets--we can receive and display those at 30fps.)

However now in Ubuntu the webcam is limiting to < 10fps using essentially the same C++ code.  Even if I do nothing other than capture (cap >> Mat) and display (imshow), it's often down around 7.5fps.

Yet the Ubuntu app Cheese doesn't appear to have this problem, frame rate looks to be at 30fps.

Does anyone know what could be going on in Ubuntu to choke the webcam frame rate down into a custom opencv app?  And how to fix?

Note I turned switchable graphics off in the BIOS for Ubuntu stability, but I think this could only help.

Comment: Whatever graphics card you're using has to effect in the webcam frame rate.

Comment: Hi Gabriela, what I'm looking for is specifics on how to fix.  Where do I make a setting change to increase the frame rate?  Why doesn't Win10 have this issue on the same laptop?